# Can you add attributes to a GridView in code behind?

Tags: c#, gridview

like so:

```
GridView1.Attributes.Add("OnRowDataBound", "gridView_OnRowDataBound",);
```

Don't want to add anything on the aspx page.  Appears after some testing that they don't get added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't an attribute, can you do this: (don't have a gridview to hand)

```
GridView1.OnRowDataBound += gridView_OnRowDataBound;
```

(In C#)